# How do you enter the Crucible?

Tags: destiny

I've gotten the Crucible bounties, and see the Crucible area on the launch screen, but can't seem to activate it... when I move the cursor over the icon and press it, nothing happens.  What am I missing?

Comment: Do you have PS Plus or Xbox Live?

Comment: Xbox Live Gold specifically if you're on the One or 360. PS Plus if you're on PS4. And nothing special, just being  online on PS3. Do you have the one you need for the system you're on?

Comment: I'm on the PS4, and don't have a PSPlus account.  :-(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To play Crucible, you require at least one of your characters to have hit level 5. You require a gold Xbox Live membership for Xbox 360 and Xbox One or a PSPlus membership for PS4. As stated in the comments, nothing for PS3. You will definitly require a connection to the internet to my knowledge.

Comment: Wow, ok... so more money to gain access to some game features.

Comment: I'm not sure definitly on the features and after I look further into it, I'll possibly update if it's something to do offline and without the features of system-link, etc...

Answer (score 0):

With the latest game update (or maybe it's because I've reached Level 20?), I can now select the Crucible area from the launch screen, and I see four icons: the first one on the left is a padlock, the other three are what I assume are faction symbols.  When I hover over the padlock icon, it says:

```
Control - Competitive Multiplayer

Dead Orbit desires new territories to expand their reach beyond the City.
```

And when I select the padlock it shows a screen that says:

```
UPGRADE REQUIRED

With Playstation Plus, you can join Fireteams and
engage in cooperative and competitive multiplayer
modes.
```

So at least they explain it now.